# check if array value exist then show second value

Tags: php, arrays

I get array like:

```
Array ( [0] => url=website1.com/etcetcetc&itag=43&quality=medium&something=nill
[1] => url=website2.com/etcetcetc&itag=18&quality=medium&something=nill
[2] => url=website3.com/etcetcetc&itag=5&quality=small&something=nill
[3] => url=website4.com/etcetcetc&itag=36&quality=small&something=nill
[4] => url=website5.com/etcetcetc&itag=17&quality=small&something=nill )
```

and after using  `foreach($links as $link)`,  I get these arrays like:

```
Array ( [url] => website.com1/etcetcetc [itag] => 43 [quality] => medium [something] => nill )
Array ( [url] => website.com2/etcetcetc [itag] => 18 [quality] => medium [something] => nill )
Array ( [url] => website.com3/etcetcetc [itag] => 5 [quality] => small [something] => nill )
Array ( [url] => website.com4/etcetcetc [itag] => 36 [quality] => small [something] => nill )
Array ( [url] => website.com5/etcetcetc [itag] => 17 [quality] => small [something] => nill )
```

How can I show selected links from it?

I want to show links with `itag` : 43 , 18 , 36. It checks if URL with one of those is available . If available, then show it's URL. It can be 1, 2 or 3 links, meaning if the link with `itag` 43 and 18 is available, then it shows the 2 URLs and if all 3 `itag` links are available then it shows those 3 links.

The url is different every time, so I can't save url in php, meaning it always has to take URL/link from array.

Currently I am showing it like:

```
echo '<a href="'.$r['url'].'">quality: '.$r['itag'].'</a>';
```

------- edit ------

here is the script/code in which i want to do that (it was made by one of my friend but he is not there now a days )

```
foreach($links as $link) { 
    echo '<a href="'.$r['url'].'">quality: '.$r['itag'].'</a><br />';
}
```

Comment: You can use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Comment: man, your edit changes the whole question IMMENSELY!!!

Comment: webeno but i need the help so you can help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just iterate through the array and if it has the number you're looking for, echo it, like this:

```
$array = array(
    array( 'url' => 'website.com1/etcetcetc', 'itag' => 43, 'quality' => 'medium', 'something' => 'nill' ),
    array( 'url' => 'website.com2/etcetcetc', 'itag' => 18, 'quality' => 'medium', 'something' => 'nill' ),
    array( 'url' => 'website.com3/etcetcetc', 'itag' => 5, 'quality' => 'small', 'something' => 'nill' ),
    array( 'url' => 'website.com4/etcetcetc', 'itag' => 36, 'quality' => 'small', 'something' => 'nill' ),
    array( 'url' => 'website.com5/etcetcetc', 'itag' => 17, 'quality' => 'small', 'something' => 'nill' )
);

$r = array();

function test($array, $number) {
    foreach($array as $r)
        if ($r['itag'] == $number) {
            echo '<a href="'.$r['url'].'">quality: '.$r['itag'].'</a>';
        }
}

test($array, 43);
test($array, 18);
test($array, 36);
```

You can test it here: http://3v4l.org/E0Pck

**EDIT**: Following your edit, here is how you can resolve this: really the only thing you need to do is to define a number variable containing the `itag` you're looking for, then check against it inside the `foreach` loop, as follows:

```
$number = 22;

foreach($links as $link) { 
    parse_str($link,$r); 
    if ($r['itag'] == $number)
        echo '<a href="'.$r['url'].'">quality: '.$r['itag'].'</a><br />';
}
```

Or if you would like to use an array as input, so you don't have to do it with each number, just wrap it inside another `foreach` loop, looping through the elements of your new `$numbers` array, as follows:

```
$numbers = array(17, 22, 36);

foreach($numbers as $number) {
    foreach($links as $link) { 
        parse_str($link,$r); 
        if ($r['itag'] == $number)
            echo '<a href="'.$r['url'].'">quality: '.$r['itag'].'</a><br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: array every time changes . so i added string which shows arrays.
$array = array($r);
but it doesn't work ( i haven't changed anything else )

Comment: my php is giving array like this:
Array ( [url] => website.com5/etcetcetc [itag] => 17 [quality] => [type] => video; codecs="avc1.64001F, mp4a.40.2" [url]  [something] => nill )
but your script is using this type of array,
array( 'url' => 'website.com5/etcetcetc', 'itag' => 17, 'quality' => 'small', 'something' => 'nill' )
mine one is not working on it i tried.

Comment: in your code if i do this print_r ($array);i get array like this
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://website.com1/etcetcetc
            [itag] => 43
            [quality] => medium
            [something] => nill
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://website.com2/etcetcetc
            [itag] => 18
            [quality] => medium
            [something] => nill
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://website.com3/etcetcetc
            [itag] => 5
            [quality] => small
            [something] => nill
   ))

Comment: but in mine i get like this:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quality] => hd720
            [itag] => 22
            [url] => http://url.com/sdfa
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quality] => medium
            [itag] => 43
            [url] => http://url.com/sdfa
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quality] => medium
            [itag] => 18
            [url] => http://url.com/sdfa
        )

)

so your arrays are aranged with 1, 2 , 3, 4 but in mine it show 0 for all i think that is the problem.

Comment: honestly, i have no idea how you got this array, to me it looks like you looped through one and then each time used `print_r`, as it just looks like a series of arrays put next to each other... if your original array was really the one on top of your question, there is no way in hell you can get the other array you mentioned by doing a foreach loop as you specified, so make sure you share the full code, otherwise this whole thing will make absolutely no sense!

Comment: dude, not here, but edit your original question... also including hints on where you took this script from (or created yourself) would be useful...

Comment: if it did, you may want to accept it as the correct answer, you know, big gray check mark ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
   $array = array( 
array( 'url' => 'website.com1/etcetcetc', 'itag' => 43, 'quality' => 'medium', 'something' => 'nill' ), 
array( 'url' => 'website.com2/etcetcetc', 'itag' => 18, 'quality' => 'medium', 'something' => 'nill' ), 
array( 'url' => 'website.com3/etcetcetc', 'itag' => 5, 'quality' => 'small', 'something' => 'nill' ), 
array( 'url' => 'website.com4/etcetcetc', 'itag' => 36, 'quality' => 'small', 'something' => 'nill' ), 
array( 'url' => 'website.com5/etcetcetc', 'itag' => 17, 'quality' => 'small', 'something' => 'nill' ) ); 

$no = '43';// whatever u want

foreach($os as $r)
{
   if (in_array(($r['itag'] == $no), $os)) {
   echo '<a href="'.$r['url'].'">quality: '.$r['itag'].'</a>';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use of `if statement` after `foreach` loop will solve your problem.

```
foreach($links as $link){ //foreach loop as you said

    if($link['itag'] == '43' || $link['itag'] == '18' || $link['itag'] == '36'){ //check if the itag is 43 or 18 or 36

    //your echo here

    }

}
```

Comment: click on 'edited X xxx ago' to see the edits i made so you can learn how to properly format your answers (or questions) ;)